# Force clean checkout each night on TeamCity

Tags: svn, teamcity

I have a build set up to trigger on changes. I also have a build trigger for 00:00 each night. But I would like that one to force a clean checkout. Is there a way to do this on the trigger or similar or do I have to create a totally new setup?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In teamcity 7.x you have a checkbox ("Clean all files in checkout directory before build") when you add a new schedule trigger.

http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD7/What%27s+New+in+TeamCity+7.0#What%27sNewinTeamCity7.0-Cleansources

see changelog.

Just update to this version.